# How do I correctly cancel a currently changing AudioParam in the Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm trying to implement volume envelopes that can restart on any given moment, even if it's already in the middle of a param-movement but I can't figure out how to do this without clicks in the resulting audio (which seem to be somewhat irregular with regards to when they occur).

Is this even possible? I see that `AudioParam.cancelScheduledValues()` *"cancels all scheduled future changes to the AudioParam"*, but I'm not sure what happens on a change that is currently going.

This is the code I'm using to start/restart the volume envelope.

```
var now = context.currentTime;
var currentVol = gain.gain.value;
gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(now);
gain.gain.setValueAtTime(currentVol, now);
gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(1, now + volAttack);
gain.gain.exponentialRampToValueAtTime(0.000001, now + volAttack + volDecay);
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, have been pulling my hair for days. The problem is that when you schedule the next note, it will cancel scheduled values, so it will totally cancel the ramp of the previous note if the decay is long enough.

Answer (score 3):

I find custom curves work more reliably and are more controllable

```
function expCurve(start, end) {
    var count = 10;
    var t = 0;
    var curve = new Float32Array(count + 1);
    start = Math.max(start, 0.0000001);
    end = Math.max(end, 0.0000001);
    for (var i = 0; i <= count; ++i) {
        curve[i] = start * Math.pow(end / start, t);
        t += 1/count;
    }
    return curve;
}


gain.gain.cancelScheduledValues(0);
var currentVol = gain.gain.value;
var now = context.currentTime;
gain.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(expCurve(currentVol, 1), now, volAttack);
gain.gain.setValueCurveAtTime(expCurve(1, 0), now + volAttack, volDecay);
```

Comment: But does that solve the problem I mention in my comment above? The problem with cancelScheduledValues is that if the cancel is scheduled before the end of the previous decay, the decay will not take place at all... because we have requested to cancel it. AFAIK there is no way to cancel a ramp halfway through and get half of the ramp. So at the moment the problem is unsolvable to me.

Comment: Did you try it? It works fine for me for exactly this use case

Comment: I will try it and get back to you. It sounds strange that this works and the standard ramps don't, because they are both handled by the same  runtime... but who knows. In my case I have linear ramps so I only need two points: start and end. Then that may fail the same way as the native linear ramps. So maybe the trick is to add more intermediate points... just guessing.

Comment: But they have different semantics, the "standard" ramps are high level with very little control over both the curve and scheduling

Comment: I tested the setValueCurveAtTime approach but did not work for me. So I will have to calculate the ramp value at current time and ramp again from there.

Answer (score 3):

After asking at the slack Web Audio channel, they explained to me that this is a known issue of the current spec.

Here is the link to the issue at GitHub: https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/344

So the short answer is that stopping ramps halfway through is currently not supported. So as a workaround, they have to be controlled at every segment.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be looking for **[`cancelAndHoldAtTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/cancelAndHoldAtTime)**.  According to MDN:

> The cancelAndHoldAtTime() property of the AudioParam interface cancels all scheduled future changes to the AudioParam but holds its value at a given time until further changes are made using other methods.

The added ability to hold the value until further changes are made seem to be what you are looking for.  I'm using the web audio API to create an amplitude envelope right now and it seems to be working.

**Note**: as of August 2022, this function is only implemented in Chrome and Safari.  See the [compatibility table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/cancelAndHoldAtTime#browser_compatibility) for updates. It does appear to be part of the official spec so it should be implemented across modern browsers eventually.

Comment: July 2022 - Still only works on Chromium-derivatives.